# Animate fullCalendar view change

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a monthly calendar with fullCalendar jQuery plugin. I want to change the view of the calendar to agendaDay whenever the user clicks on a day. It works fine, however, when I try to animate it I have some trouble, here's what I got:

```
    var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //Set up my calendar.....
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            calendario.animate({width:'toggle'},function() {
                cal.fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
                cal.fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
                calendario.animate({width:'toggle'});
            });
        }
    });
```

When I click on a day the calendar "disappears" with some effect, and when it reappears, it's just the same calendar with month view but it is set to display none.

However, and this is when the buggy part comes in, if I press alt, or F11 the agenda view appears. It's really weird.

I'm using firefox 17.0.1